# Multiview application

Tags: cocoa-touch

HI
I have one rootViewController. When apllication start load mainViewController as subview on rootController.

I want to switch view and load settingsViewController as subview on rootView and remove mainView.

When take some action, i want to remove settingsView and load mainViewController.

I try with CATransition, UIView animation but nothing.

Do you have any tutorials or eaxmples for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Utility Application" project (create a new iPhone project and select "
Utility Application").

The `-(IBAction)toggleView` method in RootViewController.m of this project should do what you want.